# In What Order are Semaphores Released in Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading

Are semaphores released FIFO, random, or using some other algorithm? Does the algorithm avoid starvation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685129(VS.85).aspx) says you cannot assume FIFO, though seems to slightly imply that FIFO is what is generally expected. I might be overstating that, though.

[This article](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-semaphores-in-c/) confirms that they are not guaranteed to be released in any order:

> Semaphores in C# are not First in
>   First Out, the implementation actually
>   does not guarantee the order in which
>   tasks are released.

Comment: Do you know if the algorithm is designed to avoid starvation?

Comment: I would guess that starvation is unlikely but not guaranteed. Just a guess, though.